# How to access a string inside a cell array?

Tags: string, matlab, cell, cells

I read the matlab help on it and still have some questions-

with strings in the cell array- I want to enter to just the first two chars of the string, how can I do that?

```
 'anscell{1,1}= '
 'LThand.jpg'
 'aa1=strcmp('LT',anscell{1:5,1}(1:2));'
```

because for now I get an error-

```
   Bad cell reference operation.
  'Error in a (line 5)'
   aa1=strcmp({'LT'},anscell{1:5,1}(1:2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`anscell` only has one element, which contains the string.

Thus, you should write

```
aa1 = strcmp('LT',anscell{1}(1:2));
```

An alternative way to only compare the first two characters is

```
aa1 = strncmp('LT',anscell{1},2);
```

Since `strncmp` works also on cell arrays, you can even drop the index, i.e.

```
aa1 = strncmp('LT',anscell,2);
```